# Problem with Accessing Individual Characters of a Char Array in C (xv6)

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I'm having trouble with accessing each individual character in an char array in C.

I declared the char array like this: `char ddd[512];` as a global constant at the beginning of the program.

Then, I read a file that contains one line of random character (which looks like this: `acdgeud`) into the char string using `int n; n = read(fd, ddd, sizeof(ddd));`. `fd` stands for file descriptor and the value is 1.

I want to access, for example, the second character of the char string, and I tried `ddd[1]`, because that is how I would do it in C++. However, it gives me everything after the first character: `cdgeud`.

Now, how can I only get one character at a time? Hope this is clear, and appreciate the help in advance!

Update: Just added part of the code:

```
char ddd[512];

void somefunc(int fd) {  

    char *another = malloc(512*sizeof(ddd));   
    int n = 0;

    while ((n = read(fd, ddd, sizeof(ddd))) > 0) {
        if ( n < 0 ) break;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            /* I'm trying to copy values in ddd to another one by one */
            another[i] = ddd[i];    /* This is not working */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `printf("%c\n", ddd[1]);` will print the char, `&ddd[1]` is indeed the string `cdgeud...` (with a missing `\0` termination.

Comment: Thanks! But I was trying to move these values into another char string one at a time, and it seems that I cannot do it like: `ddd[1] = another[1]`.

Comment: Would like to see all of the code in question. As all too common there are multiple ways to go wrong... and I've hit a good deal of them in my time.

Comment: Sorry! I understand that it is not very clear to describe the question like this, but I cannot post the code due to privacy reasons. Are there any specific reasons that you think might cause this problem?

Comment: You should give the MINIMAL code. Which is not the code you actually use.  Instead, reduce your code to the minimal number of lines which provide the wrong result.   Almost certainly it will be less than 10 lines.

Comment: I just added part of my code to the question. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edit new answer)
To step through with `for` you must test for null characters after copying the value. You could also have a separate break after the "=" assignment.

`for (int i = 0; i < n && (another[i] = ddd[i]); ++i)`

For simplicity `strncpy` can be used:
`strncpy(another, ddd, sizeof another);`

To assure \0 termination:
 `while ((n = read(fd, ddd, sizeof(ddd) - 1)) > 0) {
ddd[(sizeof ddd)-1) = '\0';   //assure null termination
}
(original)`

Per your comment I can only guess rather than answer properly. Here goes some.

`char something[2];
char ddd[512];
int n = read(fd, ddd, sizeof(ddd));
printf("c=%c\n", ddd[1]);  // print one character (c)
printf("s=%s\n", 1+ddd );        // print cdgeud, and perhaps more
// (if memset(ddd,0,sizeof ddd) happened before read things would be better).
char another[sizeof(ddd)];
ddd[1] = another[1];   // copy whatever is in another[1] into d[1].  Unpredictable as I coded it as another[] is not initialized
printf("s=%s\n", something); // unpredictable...
// if something[0] and [1] not '\0' AND ddd follows in memory (not guaranteed at all)
// then could print those followed by contentsof ddd.`

The fact that ddd is not guaranteed to be \0 terminated can be the source of accidental overruns. This works without memset().

n = read( fd, ddd, sizeof ddd );
if ( n <= 0 ) break;  // whatever is proper to detect read errors.
if ( n < sizeof(ddd) ) ddd[n] = '\0';
printf( "ddd=%.*s\n", n, ddd );   // safe

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting. How can I know if ddd is null terminated? I just included part of the code to question, could you take a look at it?

Comment: In C you can't know for sure if a string is null terminated unless you arrange [1] A null to be in the buffer that is not overlaid (memset size-1 bytes), or [2] you step through the buffer looking for the null.  C is pretty weak that way.

<code>f ( n &lt; 0 ) break</code> should be <code>n &lt;= 0</code> as 0 is EOF.